# Access is denied. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, file-upload, windows-phone-8.1, removable-storage

I am developing Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app,

I am trying to Upload document from my SD card but getting this error.

```
Access is denied. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

I have also added Capability "ID_CAP_REMOVABLE_STORAGE" in WMAppManifest file. But didn't work.

See my code below:

```
private async void UploadDocument()
{
  StorageFolder externalDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;

  StorageFolder sdCard = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

  if (sdCard != null)
  {
      //An SD card is present and the sdCard variable now contains a reference to it
  }

  else
  {
      // No SD card is present.
  }
}
```

Comment: if u are using a static method to access SD card, then avoid it.

Comment: @Gk_999 what to do and what is the static method? I am really sorry, I have no idea about this issue. Thanks man and please guide me.

Comment: I mean, if your above code is in a static method, then avoid it, i.e. create a non-static class, create an object, and then use this method. This 'MIGHT BE' a possible reason for this error, not necessary.

Comment: @Gk_999 ok, see my edit, I am still getting same kind of error. Thanks

Comment: @Romasz I have added capability in both manifest files: WMAppmanifest and package.appxmanifest, but do not getting whats going wrong. Thanks

Comment: @Romasz I think the issue may be about "File Type Association".

Comment: @Romasz should I delete "FileTypeAssociation" from "WMAppmanifest"? Thanks

Comment: @NiteshKothari I've tired without it so I think it's not needed there.

Comment: @Romasz ok man, thank you soo much, and what about "ID_CAP_REMOVABLE_STORAGE" in WMAppmanifest? should I disable it?

Comment: As I've tried - it's needed there, so leave it. Just try it and see how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WP8.1 has also new manifest file - *Package.appxmanifest* - ensure that you have also added capability there - *Location*. Also you will have to add file type association as it's *Silverlight*.

Though (I don't know why) you will have to add this the first time from code - right click on *Package.appxmanifest* file -> <kbd>View code</kbd> and add for example like this in *application/Extensions* section:

```xml
<Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
  <FileTypeAssociation Name="text">
    <DisplayName>Text file</DisplayName>
    <SupportedFileTypes>
      <FileType ContentType="text/file">.txt</FileType>
    </SupportedFileTypes>
  </FileTypeAssociation>
</Extension>
```

Once you add it and save, you be able to add/edit *FileTypeAssociations* via graphic UI.

Comment: ok, but is there any way to allow any kind of document, and what is the content type for "pdf" and "excel" files. Thank you so much. @Romasz

Comment: @NiteshKothari WP8.0 and WP8.1 *Silverlight* have [Restricted file types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207065(v=vs.105).aspx) - you won't be able to associate with them.